# How to train CNN with an RGB Image

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently building a CNN to differentiate between a rotten apple and a normal apple. I feel that it would be of great benefit if I could feed the CNN with rgb images. However, what exactly do I need to change to the following network?

```
 x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
#y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(), name="init")
y = tf.placeholder('int32')

keep_rate = 0.8
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
    #                        size of window         movement of window
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')



def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
               'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64])),
               'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64,1024])),
               'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
               'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
               'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
               'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    print("test")
    print(x)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, 7*7*64])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']
    return output
```

I have tried to change certain values however I continuously get one error after another. This network is currently meant to take 28 by 28 channel 1 grayscale images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between a gray scale and an RGB image are the number of bands, respectively 1 and 3.

So, your CNN has to take 3 bands as an input, instead of 1. The rest will be handled.

Without making your code run, you need at least to change :

```
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,32]))
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 3])
```

Comment: Also should I also change the fourth value of the strides and k size in my maxpool function to 3 as now the color channel value is three?

Comment: Done. As for your question, you only need to change the input dimension for it to work. If it doesn't, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. However, why exactly don't we alter the fourth input for the stride tensor?

Comment: I don't know your implementation, but the stride is for the sliding of the window across the image, not across its bands. Those are two different things. You should read this site : http://cs231n.github.io/